# Can't create proposal ticket

Tags: gitblit

I have a local GitBlit server. Address is :http://10.0.0.254:10101/. I create a repository on it: the address is :http://lijian@10.0.0.254:10101/r/learn-tickets.git.
Then set a user named test1 hav R(Clone) permission to the repository. The tickets settings for the repository is:[image]

Then, I clone the repository use test1 user.
And create a branch `git checkout -b topic/documentation`
Then `git push origin HEAD:refs/for/new%t=documention`, there was an error message "learn-tickets.git is not configured to receive patchsets "

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Set the config file in local server by add `tickets.service = com.gitblit.tickets.BranchTicketService`
the config file is: data/gitblit.properties.
Restart GitBlit service